# How to create a Netbeans PHP Project by using terminal in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu-12.04

How to create a Netbeans PHP Project by using terminal in Ubuntu 12.04
e.g. we have a php project under /home/username/sites/php_project_directory.
By using Netbeans GUI, we can easily create a PHP project by selecting the directory.
But is there any command by which we can create the poject from terminal using some commands, so that next time when user opens NetBeans, the project would be already created or if Netbeans was already open, then this newly created project would start reflecting in the Netbeans GUI.

Comment: Probably not but it should not be difficult to accomplish. If you open a existing project, you'll see all file are simple XML and .ini (.properties) files.

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario I am able to create a Netbeans PHP project, but I still have to open it in Netbeans, by using Open Project option?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can copy an existing project and run it through sed in order to change all details.

Comment: I used sed to make a "php code directory" into a Netbeans PHP Project. But still I had to open the project in the Netbeans.
Is there any way by which we can open the existing PHP projects in the  Netbeans through terminal?